# When does speed of characters in DBZ reach the speed of light, if at all?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

In Dragonball Z, when do the characters start moving faster than light if at all?

Comment: Just after lunch? Perhaps it would help if you explain what you mean by "when" in this case.

Comment: Like running/flying, or teleporting?

Comment: Wasnt it in the 2nd martial art contest during the original DB run in the fight against "ten" that goku went as fast as the speed of light?

Answer (score 3):

DBZ is full of weak characters moving insanely fast.
`Eg: Raditz vs Goku and Piccolo - first fight`:

--- Piccolo's "Beam cannon" (At **3:54** minutes) - a visible light weapon was easily dodged by Raditz, such that Piccolo remarks that *"He dodged it, he's faster than the speed of light!"*

Other than that, as [Ben mentioned](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/139046/46407): `Instant Transmission technique`

Comment: In Raditz's defense, he was literally stronger than *the god of the earth*.

Answer (score 0):

From the [wiki](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Instant_Transmission), the "Instant Transmition" is the only one that comes to mind when exceeding the speed of light:

> The FUNimation dub states that this technique **allows the user to travel at the speed of light**, this is not possible, as Goku has been seen using it to travel to other planets and even galaxies in a literal instant. Given that the distances from other solar systems would take light entire years to travel across, this would not be possible.

While the excerpt states that "this is not possible", I believe it is stating that their speeds *exceed* the speed of light.

Comment: Technically, maybe. It's a teleportation, though, so they're not actually moving. They're just appearing at a new place.

Comment: @CreationEdge true; since the definition of "teleportation" does state: *"Teleportation or teletransportation is the theoretical transfer of matter or energy from one point to another **without traversing the physical space** between them."*