# Goku speed at the end of the original series

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-z

The only canon reference to speed that I’ve been able to derive comes from the Saiyajin series.

The snake way has 1 million kilometres and it takes Goku between 1 day and 4 hours and 2 days to complete his way back. That will give us a sustainable speed of, at minimum, 5km per second, with his sprinting speed being probably higher.

This is on a fairly early point of his development. Is there any further canon reference (either direct or derived) on any media that state his speed later on the series?

Comment: I am not sure we can get an accurate estimate in a universe where characters routinely go beyond the speed of light. See this question for example: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139029/when-does-speed-of-characters-in-dbz-reach-the-speed-of-light-if-at-all

Comment: That's teleportation. Not FTL.